# Continuining List of Table headers to other sections?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I'm typesetting a long thesis..then suddenly realised that the **header** of **List of Tables** jumps to add to other sections like **Acknowledgement**, **Authors Declaration** etc. So, I made sure I clear for the next page: `\nextpage` e.g.

```
\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}}
\listoftables
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}
\clearpage
```

Is there something I can do to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that this answer uses `scrpage2` because the the original package isn’t included/mentioned in the question/example of BrettHarry. For this I have to use `\lehead` instead of `\lhead`.*

---

The Problem is that you set the left head (`\lehead`) to a static text (`\emph{List of Tables}`). Use `\headmark` instead.

```
\lehead{\emph{Table of contents}}
\tableofcontents

\lehead{\headmark}
```

But I think it’s not very good to set the Table of contens head manually? It seems also to be inconsistent to `\emph` only the TOC head.

### Update

This is a minimal example showing the use of my answer

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrpage2}% works too with non-KOMA-classes
    \automark{chapter}% let chapter title be the headmark
    \lehead{\headmark}% set head
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}% choose pagestyle


\usepackage{babel}
    % change TOC name
    % (this way works only with KOMA-classes or with scrbase.sty I guess)
    \renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

It shows also that the head is in italic (as `\emph` does too) by default. If you want to change the font use `\setkomafont` (see scrguien.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! It shows error `Undefined control sequence  \lehead`. Is it because Its **List of Tables?**

Comment: @BrettHarry: I’m sorry thought you where using `\lehead` instead of `\lhead`. `\lehead` comes from `scrpage2` package which is a part of KOMA-Script. I’ve added an example showing how it works. It is documented in the KOMA-Script manual. Which class and packages are you using to style the header? (`scrpage2` works also with non-KOMA-classes)

Comment: If this can’t help please add a full working minimal example to your original question.

Comment: Thanks very much! I use `fancyhdr`, but I will go for your suggestion to fix it. Cheers

Comment: @BrettHarry: I don’t know `fancyhdr` but the cause of you problem (setting a static text as headmark) is package indepent—I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have solved it. I initially had `\null\vfill`, and I took it off, now everything works fine.

Comment: @BrettHarry: Your welcome! If everything is ok and your question is answered it would be nice to accept my answer :-)